# How do I show the issue ids corresponding to all the issues in a file?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to show the issue ids corresponding to all the issues that are present in a drawing file. Currently, the issue ids are shown only when the issue is clicked. Is there a way to achieve the same using Forge development?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can list issue IDs attached to a specific document using Forge APIs like so:

1. Use [Data Management APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-tip-GET) to find the URN of a specific *version* of your document

   - the URN should start with something like `urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:`
2. Use [BIM360 APIs](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issues/retrieve-issues) to list all issues available in your BIM360 project, and if needed, filter them based on their `target_urn` property with the URN you found in the previous step

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have been able to read all the issues using the BIM360 API. However, while rendering on the viewer, I need to show the issue numbers near each of the issues. (The viewer currently shows the issue number only corresponding to the one which is selected).